# How to upload image using angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ng-file-upload

app.module.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName : ['', Validators.required],
  gender : ['', Validators.required],
  maritalStatus : ['', Validators.required],
  lastName : ['', Validators.required],
  dob : ['', Validators.required],
  nationality : ['', Validators.required],
  pic : [''],
  streetAddress : ['', Validators.required],
  city : ['', Validators.required],
  postalCode : ['', Validators.required],
  phone : ['', Validators.required],
  state : ['', Validators.required],
  country : ['', Validators.required],
  email : ['', Validators.required],
  jobTitle : ['', Validators.required],
  dateOfJoining : ['', Validators.required],
  department : ['', Validators.required],
  employeeStatus : ['', Validators.required],
  kra : ['', Validators.required],
  assignedSupervisor : ['', Validators.required],
  assignedSubordinate : ['', Validators.required],
  workExperience : ['', Validators.required],
  skills : ['', Validators.required],
  education : ['', Validators.required],
  password : ['', Validators.required]
})
}

onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
this.userService.addUser(this.userForm.value).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.model = res
    console.log(res)
  },
  error => {
    this.error = error,
    console.log(error)
  }
)
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 mt-2">
 <label for="pic">Profile Picture</label><br/>
 <input type="file" formControlname='pic' name='pic'/>
</div>
```

app.service.ts

```
addUser(formData: User) {
return this.http.post<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, formData).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

}

Eveything is working fine. I just want to know how to upload pic in angular 8. Pic is uploading in backend using node tested on postman. Can anyone help me how can i upload pic using angular, Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before making the post request convert your `formData` into actual `FormData` like described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData.

Use

```
addUser(formData: User) {
  const body = new FormData();
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(formData)){
     if(key === 'pic'){
        body.append(key, value)
     }
     body.append(key, `${value}`)
  }
  return this.http.post<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, body).pipe(catchError(this.handleError);
);
```

Then your backend should recognize the file.
Unfortunately `FormData` expects a `string` or a `blob` as the datatype for the value.

Although it is stated:

> If the sent value is different than String or Blob it will be automatically converted to String: (...)

my editor (vs code) tells me not to use a number, but convert it first.

The solution is assuming that the datatypes of the other properties inside `User` are primitives.

Comment: Its giving error ERROR in src/app/service/user.service.ts(26,25): error TS2345: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
      Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, slice
body,.append('user', formData ==> Here Error)

Comment: Ok, so you want to upload a user object, that has one property that is a file?

Comment: yes, i want to upload user object with all fields as stated above in userForm. Rest everything is working

Comment: i append it in app.componenet.ts
onSubmit() {const body = new FormData(); body.append(key,value)